# Test a java class in different OS

Tags: java, solaris, aix, hp-ux

I wanted to test my java code in these operating systems-
Solaris,HPUX and AIX. I know they have different methods to test the java code.
How do i do that?Also,should i copy my entire java project in each of the operating systems?

Comment: is it a bunch of Java Class files that has a Main one? If so, you can `jar` it and run it on those machines.

Answer (score 1):

I would package up your project e.g. `mvn package` whether you run it on one more more OSes.  The main difference between OSes is that the CLASSPATH needs a `;` on Windows and a `:` on Unix.  Otherwise, the way you test it should be exactly the same.